# Is it possible to find out the list of programs which reads a table per second in real time? - PROGRESS 4GL

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

In production, with the help of some monitor programs, we could see a particular table got read 120k times (OS Read) per second. I wonder how is this possible and looking for a program which gives full information like how many times a table gets impacted for read/write/delete per second in real time and which program is it. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 2):

protop (https://protop.com/) can display some program info

```
                                                                                                      <u> User IO Activity
 Usr# Name               PID      Flags      BlkAcc     OSRd    OSWr     Hit%   RecLk   LkHWM  CSC Age  Line# Program Name
   17 ******             2412     R4          43874      997       0   97.73%     252       0 00:01:06    168 **/***/******/menu/PreloadControls.p
   18 protop /dev/pts/6  3668805  PT3         22091       32       0   99.86%       0       0 00:00:00    870 lib/vstlib.p
   10 batchsrv           2867498  S4B           132        4       0   96.97%       0       0 00:00:03    262 *******/batchsrv-b.p
   12 batchsrv           2867755  S4B           132        8       0   93.94%       0       0 00:00:02    262 *******/batchsrv-b.p
    0 proadmin BROK      316050   LX              0        0       0    0.00%       0       0
    1 root SERV          316066   @X              0        0       0    0.00%       0       0
```

Comment: It would be better if I get this information from VST tables.

Comment: ProTop does get the information from VSTs. In this case it is mostly coming from _userio and _connect. The "uio" data collector presents the busiest connections, by default sorted by "dbaccess" also known as "logical reads" and shows you what code they are running. The default ProTop character client will also simultaneously show you the top active tables and indexes. It is very often (although not always) the case that the busiest tables, indexes, and connections are all very closely relatyed and by looking at the default screen you can zero in immediately on the code causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the *client* side you could look at [QryInfo logging](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-abl-troubleshoot-applications/page/Query-information-logging.html).

Comment: It would be better if I get this information from VST tables if possible.

Comment: Which VST were you thinking about? Pick one from this list https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-database-management-122/page/Virtual-system-table-summaries.html - While it can be fun thinking up imaginary functionality, it does not get you any closer to a solution.